# Implementing permanent ban into a mysql database where ban time is "datetime". How to?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, permanent

I have a mysql column banneduntil. It's type is "datetime". How would I implement a permanent ban? (I've already implemented a basic ban system with admin/mod defined time). Should I just create a boolean column called "permabanned" and just check if its true or false?

Comment: Yes, use a permaban table/column; if someone is permanently banned it makes no sense to waste resources assessing the dates.

Comment: Just set the banneduntil date to 31-Dec-9999.  **If** your system is still running then, they'll be too busy dealing with the y10k problem to worry about a permanently banned member (dead for nearly 10,000 years) trying to get back in.  Will the query be:  is personX banned now? or is personX not ever supposed to be here?

Comment: Please state what table this column `banneduntil` belongs to, so you can get more accurate solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Provided that `banneduntil` is in a table called `bans`:

Set the `banneduntil` column to `NULL`. This correctly reflects the meaning of a permanent ban, since it is a ban for an indefinite period.

Comment: if banneduntil is null then person is not banned, surely?

Comment: I assume that there is a table for bans, until stated otherwise in the question. If it is just a field in a user table, I would go for the 'for-a-long-long-time' implementation, i.e. setting the value to 31-Dec-9999 as you mentioned.

Comment: +1 Actually, that would be a more correctly normalised structure (which I'm obviously not used to).  Still, I bet it's a column in a member table (coz i'm not the only one).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this depends on what the table contains to denote "not banned"?

Assuming Null/Zero (0000-00-00 00:00:00) then I'd suggest the Maximum DateTime (9999-12-31 23:59:59).

Whilst this offers the risk of another Y2K (Y10K? anyone) I suspect that year 9999 will have bigger issues, assuming your code is still in operation by then.

Comment: Worst case scenario is that the banned user rejoins after 9999-12-31. For *most* banned users this is an acceptable scenario :-)